# Permision denied with vercel deployment

Tags: deployment, vite, vercel

I am trying to deploy a website imported from GitHub with Vercel, and it keeps returning an error when building. The command "npm run build" works perfectly in local in vscode, but when Vercel runs it it gets the following error:

[image]

What should I do?